# .html file extension using codeigniter from localhost to live server

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

Hi i have this website and i tried to change the url and added the suffix into .html so when the user navigate into pages the url goes something like this `http://localhost/test/contacts.html` i configured the config/config.php file the `$config['url_suffix']` i added .html. When i tried to run in my localhost,it is ok, and when i uploaded it to live server errors goes like this 404 (page not found) i already added the .htaccess in the live server what other configuration will i add this? can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you move your framework to the other machine, don't forget you must change it's config too. perhaps you miss the `base_url` address.

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://yourserveraddress/'
```

Comment: oh i forgot to add this. Ill try this when i got home

Comment: Hi you there??? ahm i already added the base_url site address.,Its still not working?? please heeeellllp

Comment: i forgot to change the .htaccess that's why its not working when i added the config['base_url']

Answer (score 0):

What OS are you developing on locally, and what OS is the server running?

Also, if you are serving static HTML files, why are you bothering with a framework?

Have you followed this guide: http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/76708/?

You'll want:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/static/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ /static/$1.html [L]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|static)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

in your .htaccess file and then simply drop your static files into the /static/ folder.

Comment: windows 7 ultimate and my OS in live server is i think linux

Comment: no not all files are HTML like there are certain part in my webpage like the homepage there is a news and updates and in there it is dynamic and the programs part are the images and that is dynamic part

Comment: ill try this i did not see that link

Comment: it wont work... i tried the htaccess on my live server